# USB visible in lsusb and /dev/disk/by-id and dmesg but not fdisk -l

Tags: usb, mount

I am trying to mount a usb device so I can copy files. The device is a 64GB NTFS format that is visible in windows.

I am running Ubuntu server 16.05

It is not visible using fdisk

```
root@seba1:/# sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 838.1 GiB, 899898718208 bytes, 1757614684 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 262144 bytes / 786432 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x769ca931

Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       1536    1500671    1499136   732M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1502206 1757614079 1756111874 837.4G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1502208 1757614079 1756111872 837.4G 8e Linux LVM

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/mapper/seba1--vg-root: 836.4 GiB, 898075983872 bytes, 1754054656 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 262144 bytes / 786432 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/seba1--vg-swap_1: 976 MiB, 1023410176 bytes, 1998848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 262144 bytes / 786432 bytes
```

I can see it in lsbulk but with limited detail

```
root@seba1:~# lsblk -a
NAME                 MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                    8:0    0 838.1G  0 disk
├─sda1                 8:1    0   732M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                 8:2    0     1K  0 part
└─sda5                 8:5    0 837.4G  0 part
  ├─seba1--vg-root   252:0    0 836.4G  0 lvm  /
  └─seba1--vg-swap_1 252:1    0   976M  0 lvm
sdb                    8:16   1         0 disk
sr0                   11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
loop0                  7:0    0         0 loop
loop1                  7:1    0         0 loop
loop2                  7:2    0         0 loop
loop3                  7:3    0         0 loop
loop4                  7:4    0         0 loop
loop5                  7:5    0         0 loop
loop6                  7:6    0         0 loop
loop7                  7:7    0         0 loop
root@seba1:~# man fsck
root@seba1:~# lsblk -a -f
NAME                 FSTYPE      LABEL UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
sda
├─sda1               ext2              000a4ad9-d3ff-4120-85c4-30966a24459b   /boot
├─sda2
└─sda5               LVM2_member       T6HYsz-8kKE-ClUV-NfDc-wX2Y-y05b-NIYN1V
  ├─seba1--vg-root   ext4              45a0bed5-eab3-4232-8527-f60f862dae1b   /
  └─seba1--vg-swap_1 swap              88038088-af5f-4465-94e6-1f3e49139b91
sdb
sr0
loop0
loop1
loop2
loop3
loop4
loop5
loop6
loop7
```

I can see the device in /dev/disk/by-id

```
root@seba1:/dev/disk/by-id# ls -la /dev/disk/by-id | grep "\->"
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Aug 20 14:01 ata-hp_DVD_D_DS8DBSH_425440900266 -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Aug 20 14:01 dm-name-seba1--vg-root -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Aug 20 14:01 dm-name-seba1--vg-swap_1 -> ../../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Aug 20 14:01 dm-uuid-LVM-HpyMYVdCN2dahuU4r0hFMh9XsK9nNpViDQVZ5N3ngowVgfjsb5vNzbba70ZVAMny -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Aug 20 14:01 dm-uuid-LVM-HpyMYVdCN2dahuU4r0hFMh9XsK9nNpVipv6yfYy2s2Xwm9vmtZd98LSHRc4kpMcy -> ../../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Aug 20 14:01 lvm-pv-uuid-T6HYsz-8kKE-ClUV-NfDc-wX2Y-y05b-NIYN1V -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Aug 20 14:01 scsi-3600508b1001c1054a4cee49b8df4f462 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Aug 20 14:01 scsi-3600508b1001c1054a4cee49b8df4f462-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Aug 20 14:01 scsi-3600508b1001c1054a4cee49b8df4f462-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Aug 20 14:01 scsi-3600508b1001c1054a4cee49b8df4f462-part5 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Aug 20 14:18 usb-SMI_USB_MEMORY_BAR-0:0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Aug 20 14:01 wwn-0x600508b1001c1054a4cee49b8df4f462 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Aug 20 14:01 wwn-0x600508b1001c1054a4cee49b8df4f462-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Aug 20 14:01 wwn-0x600508b1001c1054a4cee49b8df4f462-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Aug 20 14:01 wwn-0x600508b1001c1054a4cee49b8df4f462-part5 -> ../../sda5
```

it does appear in the usb-devices list

```
root@seba1:/dev/disk/by-id# usb-devices

T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 2
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=04.04
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.4.0-159-generic ehci_hcd
S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:1a.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 6
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=8087 ProdID=0024 Rev=00.00
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=05 Cnt=01 Dev#=  4 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=090c ProdID=3267 Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=Silicon Motion,Inc.
S:  Product=SM3269AB MEMORY BAR
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
```

And I can see it in dmesg

```
[ 1005.556418] usb 1-1.6: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 1005.709375] usb 1-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=3267
[ 1005.709382] usb 1-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1005.709386] usb 1-1.6: Product: SM3269AB MEMORY BAR
[ 1005.709390] usb 1-1.6: Manufacturer: Silicon Motion,Inc.
[ 1005.710451] usb-storage 1-1.6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1005.710720] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-1.6:1.0
[ 1006.709965] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SMI      USB MEMORY BAR   1000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[ 1006.710898] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 1006.713395] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

an attempt to mount fails

```
root@seba1:~# mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb /media/kevUSB
Error opening '/dev/sdb': No medium found
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb': No medium found
```

How do I mount this drive?

Answer (score 0):

You have the drive (`/dev/sdb`). You can see what filesystem it has with `lsblk -f`, then read `man fsck` and `man fsck.{filesystem}`. and `man mount`

Here's how I `mount` my `VFAT` mp3 players:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ bash -x bin/fixmp3 /dev/sdb
+ # setup and arg parsing omitted ...
+ target=/dev/sdb
+ mntdir=/home/walt/mnt/mp3/sdb
+ [[ -d /home/walt/mnt/mp3/sdb ]]
+ sudo umount /dev/sdb
umount: /dev/sdb: not mounted
+ sudo fsck.vfat -w -y /dev/sdb
fsck.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
/dev/sdb: 206 files, 108052/958507 clusters
+ sudo mount -t vfat -o rw,user,users,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2 /dev/sdb /home/walt/mnt/mp3/sdb
+ [[ 0 -gt 0 ]]
+ exit 0
```

Comment: it is visible with the -a flag